Is there WCAG certification?
Unsurprisingly, our company has finally run into some organizations that work with us requiring compliance. This has led to someone asking how we get "WCAG 2.2" certification. This has come to the UX desk to look over. We have new products that pass AA pretty well, but there are older products still not rebuilt.
Is there even a real "certification" - other than running a test and showing the results? When I do a search for 'certification' I only see websites promoting that they'll review our site, and provide a document stating we're compliant. But, beyond implementing any UI and code recommendations, I'm not seeing some truly legitimate "certification" beyond these company-specific unregulated offerings.
I've seen that W3C has a certification for a person to profess understanding, but not for a site.

You should ask these organizations what requirements the product must meet. WCAG is merely a tool that provides guidance on how to make a site or product compliant with accessibility standards defined by the country, industry or other organizations on which your business depends.

Some of these are state institutions. I can find a legal statute stating that sites must comply with WCAG 2.1  — a statement that's somehow both specific and vague at the same time. :) How we document that compliance, is not mentioned.

How strict is their requirement and how do they check for compliance? If they can’t answer that maybe you shouldn’t bother. Having some results from audit tools like axe/lighthouse should be enough. Just know that WCAG compliance doesn’t guarantee accessibility.

The closest thing to what you're asking for is a WCAG Conformance Claim, which does have a normative definition in the WCAG themselves:

Conformance claims are not required. Authors can conform to WCAG
2.2 without making a claim. However, if a conformance claim is made, then the conformance claim must include the following information:

Date of the claim
Guidelines title, version and URI "Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 2.2 at https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/"
Conformance level satisfied: (Level A, AA or AAA)
A concise description of the web pages, such as a list of URIs for which the claim is made, including whether subdomains are included
in the claim.
A list of the web content technologies relied upon.


The W3C publish a document called the Website Accessibility Conformance Evaluation Methodology (WCAG-EM), which describes the typical process for assessing a given web site for WCAG compliance.
There are third parties who will perform conformance assessments for you, but there is no such thing as a certification authority with official authorisation to make claims about conformance than you are yourself. Most accessibility consulting firms provide some kind of certificate of conformance (WebAIM provide one such service) which typically include the W3C's required information as stated above, along with their own proprietary additional information such as evaluation methodology to lend it some kind of special significance, but the W3C does not provide any formal accreditation of those entities or their methods.

Yes, I think you'll want to get one of your sites WCAG verified and use that as your company's proof that they certified for the work. You could also try getting some of your colleagues or yourself to get the individual certifications, which your company can use to further solidify their position as WCAG compliant. Sort of like how if you want a government contract you'll need people with certain levels of experience and qualifications (bachelors, PhD, etc.).

This isn't an answer to the question though. OP is asking if certification is actually available, not whether they should get their site verified.

@JonW he then immediately states that he couldn't find a certification for a company, so I answered with that in mind. My research found the same. I only found  WAS (web accessibility specialist), which is why I suggested getting some of their members certified should lead to their company also being certified by proxy
